# Is resting affected by office work?

Tags: workout-routines, rest, muscle-gain

I'm a computer programmer and I basically sit around for 8 hours each day just staring at the screen, coding.
I started working out for about 3 months now. I'm working out from 12:00 to 12:40 pm before lunch and eat afterwards.

Is my workout time okay? Or should I work out in the afternoon, after working hours (6:00 or 8:00 pm perhaps) so that I'd go straight to resting?

Am I losing gains when I work out and don't rest afterwards, but do office work instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between sleeping immediately after a workout and sleeping a half-workday later is negligible. The more significant difference, which is still pretty minor, is the increased energy many people feel earlier in the day. Generally speaking, most people are slightly stronger in early-day efforts than they are in late workouts. (Their mobility is greater in the evening, however, and there are other fluctuations.)

The best time to work out is when you have the time. Lunchtime sounds fine for you, as long as you have time to get some food after the workout.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Dave, the best time is when you make it. The important moment here is to understand that you should strive to start each workout session at the same time. Thus the body will develop a habit of working out at certain hours. This way it will be "prepared" for a workout and your workouts will go smoother.

I used to workout in the morning, in the evening, at noon. Depending on what my schedule was. Last year I was also working in a software company and my work day would start at 11am. This way I made sure to workout in the mornings before work. That's when I felt most energetic, after a day in front of the computer I would feel lethargic and lazy to do much. It can be different for everybody. As long as you don't skip on your meals and don't skip your workouts you shall have no problems regardless of the schedule that you choose for your workouts!